# Error launching a Spark cluster on AWS EC2

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch a Spark cluster on EC2 using the following script:

`spark-ec2/spark-ec2 -k keyfile.pem --identity-file=keyfile.pem --region=us-west-2 --zone=us-west-2a --copy-aws-credentials --instance-type t2.micro --worker-instances 1 launch pg-hello-cluster`

Where I have configured the variables:

```
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
```

This throws the following errors, and it seems like its an issue with the `urllib2` library?

```
- Downloading boto...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark-ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 169, in <module>
    setup_external_libs(external_libs)
  File "spark-ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 143, in setup_external_libs
    lib_version=lib["version"]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Double check the version of OpenSSL that your version of Python is linked to. It is probably too old. Note: T2.micro is too small for Spark. 8 GB is the recommended minimum - 2 GB is the bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks! Updating the openSSL version fixed the previous error. But now, there's an error for invalidKeypairs `ERROR:boto:400 Bad Request
ERROR:boto:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidKeyPair.NotFound</Code><Message>The key pair 'gutenberg-project.pem' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>ba9d906b-ee28-4e74-8bef-9c731fd3a49e</RequestID></Response>`

Comment: Apparently this happens due to a region mismatch, tried that but didn't work. Let me see what else I can do

Comment: The problem is that you are using -k filename when you should be using the key pair name. Look this up in the AWS EC2 console. AND key pairs are region specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is caused by using a version of OpenSSL that is too old for current TLS protocol support.